# What is the right /best place to store Configatron configuration in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, initialization, reload, configatron

I'm using the [configatron gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/configatron/2.8.3/frames) for a new Rails app that is backed up by ActiveRecord. Some of my configatron settings are set in a file and some are pulled from DB, as they will change from time to time, here are a couple of lines from my configatron.rb

```
configatron.app.uptime.start = Time.now
configatron.email.signature = Setting.where(:keyname => "email_signature").first.value.to_s unless Setting.where(:keyname => "email_signature").first.nil?
```

Since this app sends multiple emails from multiple mailers - that is a good way to keep this global config in one place, plus it reduces db lookups for signature. If for some reason site admin decides to change it - they can do it through web admin interface that will update my settings table ( tied to Setting model).

This is all jolly & good, however what is the best place to store configatron.rb? Right now it's sitting in my initializers folder. Which means it will load once on application startup - which is good, however if one of the settings changes - site admin decides to tweak email signature to mention a new promotional website - in order for the change to take effect - I would need to restart app ( running passenger - so it trivial to do `touch tmp/restart.txt` from code).  However that means other configatron settings that I don't wont to reset ( such as my uptime start timestamp) will be reset as well.

So what is a better place to move my configatron.rb and load from so that it would allow for 
loading once on startup and then changing some configs without and app restart?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that putting it in an initializer is the right place to store it.

if you want to update the configuration without restarting the application, you would normally setup a "watchdog". some process that pulls the database regulary to check for configuration updates. you could also implement some kind of callback that pushes changed configurations to your app.

Answer (score 1):

when i put configatron to initializer, Rails environment variables load before loading configatron settings. As effect, middleware loaded in Rails configuration (config/environments/production.rb) was unable to use configatron variables.

so i ended up loading it as first thing in environment.rb instead

Comment: That is actually desired behavior for me, as I only store application settings there, that would need to be loaded after the environment is loaded. Actually based on which environment app is in ( prod vs test/dev) I load different settings.